# Is it possible to add new waypoints to Dolly Track in Unity CinemachineVirtualCamera on the go?

Tags: unity, camera

I'm making a racing game "on rails" that utilizes generated map (similar to outrun). The map is made out of chunks that appear every time player crosses a Trigger area on the chunk that is 3 chunks away from the end.
To make camera go steady through designed path I need something like Dolly track. The problem with using it is that it uses an Array to store all the waypoints of the track. Which means I cannot simply add another element to the Array end because it will replace the old array with a new one. (I tested it and indeed - Only the last chunk has any dolly points)
[image]
Do I need to write  a new dollyTrack or is there a  simpler way to have newly generated points added to DollyTrack ? Is there a better camera package for it ?

Comment: Have you tried to just use the array function `AddRange()`? And you did not include how you tried to manipulate the array

Comment: Can I use it on arrays as they are ? Tutorials often employ a list like here : 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/merge-two-arrays-using-chash-addrange-method

For my solution I did something simillar : 1. made a list with all required waypoint points and then  I used ToArray() and substituted the first array with the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you write substitute, you are replacing something. If that is working, that is a valid solution. AddRange will append at the end of it, which was what you were asking in the question

Comment: Addrange works for lists from the tutorials I see on the internet. 
Can I really use Array.AddRange(array) ?
My IDE says it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I did not test it's usefulness in terms of smooth transition I made a version of dolly track that uses list and seems to add/subtract waypoints progressively.

The working solution to the problem of smooth transition ended up being simple replacement of one point array with another. It didn't work for me at first because of dolly camera "dumping" variables. The dumping caused the camera to glitch-teleport to the end of the new track and then slide back to the beginning. When you set it to 0 the transition itself is smooth.

However there seems to be other problem arising. The generated path sometimes folds itself in places where the distance between points is not roughly divisible by the `CinemachineSmoothPath` "resolution" variable. It mainly affects camera on track.
So I simplified the system by using 3rd person camera that follows a cart on a dolly track instead of having a camera also being confined to a dolly track.